# Multiplication with two demical places

Tags: javascript

im trying to multiply the two value with textbox but im not getting the right answer when they had 2 decimal places. sample output 5.50*5 = 25. i would like to print like this 27.50 instead of 25.

```
<script>
  if (elm["ItemPrice"].value != "" && elm["ItemQuantity"].value != "") {
    elm["TotalSale"].value = parseInt(elm["ItemPrice"].value) * parseInt(elm["ItemQuantity"].value);
  }
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('multi').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry my friend not so familiar in the language

Comment: You're using `parseInt()` which casts the values to integers so any decimal value will be lost. Example: `parseInt(10.5)` will just return `10`. Remove the parseInt() and try with that.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how the added code have anything to do with the question or the above code?

Comment: so how i solve this issue?

Comment: Test it without using `parseInt()`. You should also post example data/values and show us the expected output and what you're currently getting. Just remember that calculating with floats can give you wrong results: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: YES! Thank you sir. Big big thank you @MagnusEriksson now is working . How about semi colon? sample 5,500.00

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you mean. What semicolon? Do you mean comma `,`? Well `5,500.00` is not a valid number in javascript. you need to change it to `5500.00` for javascript to know what it is. You can do that by simply removing the comma: `elm['ItemPrice'].value.replace(',', '') * elm['ItemQuantity'].value`.

Answer (score 0):

This would work. You are converting the value in Int and the value is in Float

```
<script>
  if (elm["ItemPrice"].value != "" && elm["ItemQuantity"].value != "") {
    elm["TotalSale"].value = parseFloat(elm["ItemPrice"].value) * elm["ItemQuantity"].value;
  }
</script>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('multi').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think the "ItemQuantity" should be cast as a float. Quantity tends to be integers.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Well to be fair sometimes I order a Pint of Guiness and a half of Bitter.... So I have something to drink while the Guiness is settling:)

Comment: without parseInt its working very perfectly. but, im getting the 55.33 * 303 = 16764.989999999998. parseFloat will solve my issue?

Comment: @RiggsFolly - Fair enough. I should have specified _"unless Guiness is involved_ :-)

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hi sir do you know how to print semi colon the textbox? bytheway thank you. i would like to see the output like this 5,5000.55

Comment: @Malandi - It's not a semi colon, it's a comma. Try using the [Intl.NumberFormat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat) function. I don't write much JS myself these days so that was just want I found on a quick search. You need to read that page and see if it would work and how to use it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson thank you but idk how to use that. i tried but is not working.

Comment: @Malandi - Then you need to do more testing/research. Since the original question has been resolved, you need to post another question if you have more issues you need help with. However, you need to do some extensive research and make some attempts yourself before asking though.